# RestSharp to WCF as JSON date formatting / serializing

Tags: wcf, restsharp

I have a WCF Method that takes in a list of "Timestamps"

```
public bool SyncTimestamps(IList<Timestamp> timestamps)
```

For the life of me I cannot get the client to pass values to the host in a format that it is happy with using RestSharp.  The problem appears to be with dateformatting.

**Attempt 1**

```
var request = new RestRequest("Timestamp/SyncTimestamps", Method.POST);
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
request.AddBody(timestamps);
```

**Output 1**

```
"[{\"ID\":1,\"JobId\":654321,\"TimestampSelected\":\"2013-08-05T13:51:13.6201529Z\",\"TimestampActual\":\"2013-08-05T13:51:13.6201529Z\",\"Type\":1,\"Active\":false}]"
```

**Error 1**

> DateTime content '2013-08-05T13:51:13.6201529Z' does not start with
>   '/Date(' and end with ')/' as required for JSON.'

I read that this was a problem with the RestSharp serializer so I replaced with Json.Net which produces a slightly different date string.

**Attempt 2**

```
var request = new RestRequest("Timestamp/SyncTimestamps", Method.POST);
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
request.AddBody(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(timestamps));
```

**Output 2**

```
{application/json="[{\"ID\":1,\"JobId\":654321,\"TimestampSelected\":\"2013-08-05T14:54:33.9261815+01:00\",\"TimestampActual\":\"2013-08-05T14:54:33.9251814+01:00\",\"Type\":1,\"Active\":false}]"}
```

**Error 2**

```
The exception message is 'Expecting state 'Element'.. 
Encountered 'Text' with name '', namespace ''. '. See server logs for more details. 
The exception stack trace is: 

at ReadArrayOfTimestampFromJson(XmlReaderDelegator , XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplexJson , XmlDictionaryString , XmlDictionaryString , CollectionDataContract ) 
at System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.JsonCollectionDataContract.ReadJsonValueCore(XmlReaderDelegator jsonReader, XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplexJson context) 
at System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.JsonDataContract.ReadJsonValue(XmlReaderDelegator jsonReader, XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplexJson context) at
```

Can anyone suggest a way to produce a dateformat that WCF service will be happy to accept and deserialize?  The docs on MSDN state that the following format is required.

> DateTime values appear as JSON strings in the form of
>   "/Date(700000+0500)/", where the first number (700000 in the example
>   provided) is the number of milliseconds in the GMT time zone, regular
>   (non-daylight savings) time since midnight, January 1, 1970.

**UPDATE :**

I found a settings as part of JSON.Net that allows me to transfer the date into the format that WCF appears to be askign for.

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings() { DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat };
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, settings);
```

This appears to have done the job in creating the serialized string.

```
{application/json="[{\"ID\":1,\"JobId\":654321,\"TimestampSelected\":\"\\/Date(1375713542908+0100)\\/\",\"TimestampActual\":\"\\/Date(1375713542908+0100)\\/\",\"Type\":1,\"Active\":false}]"}
```

My service however still rejects this with "The exception message is 'Expecting state 'Element'.."

Answer (score 0):

Aside from JSON.Net, there's another JSON serializing library that will do this for you: https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.Text/

```
var request = new RestRequest("Timestamp/SyncTimestamps", Method.POST);
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;

var json = JsonSerializer.SerializeToString(timestamps);
request.AddParameter("application/json", json, ParameterType.RequestBody);
```

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there.  You just have to add the parameter to the request manually, bypassing the faulty RestSharp serializer.

```
var request = new RestRequest("Timestamp/SyncTimestamps", Method.POST);
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings() { DateFormatHandling=DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat };
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(timestamps,settings);

request.AddParameter("application/json",json,null,ParameterType.RequestBody);
```