# Rest Sharp is not serializing dates

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net, restsharp

Surely the default in the latest Restsharp should be able to seralise a `Datetime.

Below is my request build

```
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
//request.JsonSerializer = new MyJsonSerializer(); // When applying JSON.Net serialisation 
request.Resource = "SaveBooking";
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
request.AddBody(booking);

return Execute<bool>(request);
```

I have tried implementing JSON.NET Serializer and integrating with `restsharp` [as suggested in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060440/restsharp-to-wcf-as-json-date-formatting-serializing), which links through to their notes. But i have the same issue.

The JSON it is building is as follows:

```
 "BookingDate": "2014-11-13T09:31:02.0667967+00:00",
 "StartTime": "2014-11-13T10:30:00",
 "EndTime": "2014-11-13T17:00:00",
```

And the errors im getting are of the form below when trying to deserialise.

```
DateTime content '2014-11-12T16:20:30.4635576Z' does not start with '\/Date(' and end with ')\/' as required for JSON.'.
```

It is clear it is not serializing dates. But i have no idea why. Or how to fix it.

I am deserializing with the rest endpoint

```
     [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "/SaveBooking")]
    Boolean SaveBooking(RoomBookingEntry Booking);
```

with parameter

```
  public class RoomBookingEntry
{
    public DateTime BookingDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndTime { get; set; } 
}
```

}

Comment: The error message you're getting doesn't match the JSON you've provided - are the spaces there or not? And how are you deserializing?

Comment: @JonSkeet They are of the same notation, but the json was saved from an earlier debug of the same thing. Aka, the times dont match. I am de-serialisng as attached in my question.

Comment: They're not the same - one has spaces within the date/time values (which is bizarre) and the other doesn't. Do the values *actually* look like `"2014-11-12T16: 34: 16.9681998Z"` or `"2014-11-12T16:34:16.9681998Z"`?

Comment: @JonSkeet Oh i see now. Okay, teh first one i put in a Json formmater. so maybe its been editted badly. The second one is definately correct, as it is the error i get back. I will double check.

Comment: So are you using RestSharp for both serialization *and* deserialization? (It's fairly unclear what the bigger context is here... more information would be very useful.)

Comment: @JonSkeet see edit, of actual json. Rest sharp is used to send the request to my C# webservice. I hoped that the endpoints and default deserialization would work on recieving end. Aka, no restsharp is used. I will edit in my recieve endpoints fully

Comment: Right, so this is presumably using `DataContractJsonSerializer` for the  deserialization. That was what I was looking for from the start - there are lots of different ways you *could* have been deserializing...

Comment: @JonSkeet Sorry, i apologise for not providing enough information. I know its irritating to have to apply guess work. Does anything stand out to what is wrong. I assume the Json is not being built correctly? or is it a seperate standard for serializing. If you need more info let me know

Comment: The problem is that there's no single "right" way of representing a DateTime in JSON. See http://www.hanselman.com/blog/OnTheNightmareThatIsJSONDatesPlusJSONNETAndASPNETWebAPI.aspx. I can't find any way of persuading RestSharp to serialize `DateTime` to the `new Date(...)`  format... you might want to look into whether you can persuade `DataContractJsonSerializer` to accept the ISO-8601 format...

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for the guidance. I have managed to get it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jon Skeet mentions. They are expecting different formats, so do not recognise each other.

Using the serializer found here: 
https://github.com/khalidabuhakmeh/Ducksboard/tree/master/Ducksboard/Serializers

I have been able to get `RestSharp` to send `datetime` in the format that `DataContractJson` expects.

Bound using:

```
   var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
   request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;

   request.JsonSerializer = new RestSharpDataContractJsonSerializer();

   request.Resource = "SaveBooking";
   request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json"); // May not be needed
   request.AddBody(booking);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can tell JSON.Net to use the correct when serializing dates like so:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings() { DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat };
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, settings);
```

There's another JSON serializing library that does this by default: https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.Text/

```
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
request.Resource = "SaveBooking";

var json = JsonSerializer.SerializeToString(booking);
request.AddParameter("application/json", json, ParameterType.RequestBody);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the Newtonsoft.Json serializer that you probably already have in your project.  You just have to add the parameter to the request manually, bypassing the faulty RestSharp serializer.

```
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
request.Resource = "SaveBooking";
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings() { DateFormatHandling=DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat };
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(booking,settings);

request.AddParameter("application/json",json,null,ParameterType.RequestBody);



return Execute<bool>(request);
```

Comment: This worked for me. Also had to make sure that my [DataMember] was set in the [DataContract] for my Datetime field.